# runtime_error was not declared in this scope for g++ 4.1.2

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

The same code is working fine on gcc 4.5.2 but when trying to compile it on gcc 4.1.2, I get the error `‘runtime_error’ was not declared in this scope`.

I do have

```
#include <stdexcept>
```

Is this a problem with gcc 4.1.2?

Code excerpt

```
// Constructor
if (resource cannot be acquired)
  throw std::runtime_error("Blah Blah");
```

Comment: Have you specified any paths to search for header files. The compiler may be picking up a non standard header file?

Comment: All my extra include paths are in my source folders and there is no file named stdexcept. If your hypothesis is correct, how does it explain that my code works in 4.5.2 and not in 4.1.2?

Comment: One thing you could try would be to tempararily edit the stdexcept from your STL implementation to see if it is included by adding something in the lines of #warning "stdexcept included!" at its beginning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio says that `runtime_error` should be defined in `<stdexcept>`, so I'm guessing that GCC 4.1.2 is just out of date here.

Comment: This is a automatic search of the header file issue. I got several machines of different linux flavor.  On some machines I need to include <stdexcept> on others I don't have to.  For safety, just include the <stdexcept> header.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have `using namespace std;` or `using std::runtime_error;`? If not, then you need to fully qualify the name and use `std::runtime_error` rather than just `runtime_error`.

Comment: Yes, my code calls std::runtime_error in a fully qualified manner.

Answer (score 2):

gcc 4.1 is relatively old. 4.5 is more standard compliant. Maybe you triggered a compiler's bug