# 'runtime_error' was not declared in this scope while trying to generate so file with Android-NDK

Tags: c++, android-ndk, g++, native

I read the following post but I think it doesn't apply in my case : [runtime_error was not declared in this scope for g++ 4.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527091/runtime-error-was-not-declared-in-this-scope-for-g-4-1-2)

My problem is almost the same but I'm trying to compile a file with Android-NDK (r8c), I checked if the NDK had stdexcept.h and it does. Here are my sources :

```
#include <stdexcept>

class RandomName : public std::runtime_error {
public:
  ...
};
```

And here's my Android.mk file :

```
# File: Android.mk
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := interfacetest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := file.cpp
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -frtti

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Should I add some lines to the Android.mk file ?

Comment: And, is class runtime_error in stdexcept header?

Comment: Yes runtime_error class is inside the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good explanation of this in the latest NDK docs in the file CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html although I'll produce the relevant bits here. For the default **system** runtime, the only headers provided are:

> cassert cctype cerrno cfloat climits cmath csetjmp csignal cstddef
>   cstdint cstdio cstdlib cstring ctime cwchar new stl_pair.h typeinfo
>   utility

As of NDK release 8, the only runtime that supports exceptions is **gnustl** which you can link statically by adding the following to your *Application.mk* not Android.mk:

> APP_STL := gnustl_static

Even then you'll need an additional step:

> The NDK toolchain supports C++ exceptions, since NDK r5, however all
>   C++ sources are compiled with -fno-exceptions support by default, for
>   compatibility reasons with previous releases.
>
> To enable it, use the new LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES variable in your
>   Android.mk, as in:
>
> ```
> LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions
> ```

Comment: Also if I add LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions, I won't be able to use dynamic_cast anymore ? Is that right ?

Comment: I haven't tried to combine them but my understanding of the docs is that you can enable both rtti and exceptions via:  LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES := rtti features